# Excel Conditional Formatting - Multiple Rules/Rows

Tags: conditional-formatting, excel-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDP1c.jpg)I am creating a table with a schedule events over the course of a year. There are three repeating events, and I would like to highlight the entire row of each repeating event in a different color. I thought that would be a useful thing to do for planning purposes in any sort of schedule or calendar.

So, for instance:

If Event 1, highlight table row in green

If Event 2, highlight table row in orange

If Event 3, highlight table row in blue

I have successfully created a rule for each of them that highlights the individual cell in the desired color, but it does not highlight the entire row within the table.  I have also successfully created a rule that will highlight the entire row of the table for one event.

However, I cannot get multiple rules that highlight entire table rows to work concurrently.

Is Excel 2016 capable of doing this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: Addition of sample formula and screenshot. Thank you Alan!

Sample formula: =$E101="Event 1"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to apply multiple rules in the manner you describe.

You haven't posted samples of the rules, nor a screenshot, so I can't comment on why it isn't working for you.

Inside, here is a mock-up showing you a working row-based multi-layered conditional formatting.

Note that how you are aligning your events is important - if you can have event collisions (i.e. more than one event on the same row), then you will need to decide how to handle the collision (e.g. order of priority or add additional rules for mixed colours).

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Update based on added details*:

Your schedule with conditional formatting applied:

[image]

The rules:

[image]

Note: If you apply the rules and they don't immediately show up correctly, check the rules. When I entered these, Excel would corrupt the formula and I had to reenter them.

Also note the $E to lock the formula to the Event column.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! the formula that I've been trying to use is this: =$E*="Event 1" for each rule, but it hasn't been coming out quite correctly, and I realized based on what you said above that my formatting might have something to do with that. Working on a screenshot now

Comment: Hi Alan, I added in a screenshot and a sample of my formula into the original post. I apologize if this isn't super clean right now - my laptop is updating and I'm doing this from a phone. I would appreciate any further input that you have, and thank you for your help!